# Why is the 100*0.07 equal to 6.9999....?

Tags: matlab

One of my friends wrote the following in Matlab and the outputs are little weird:

```
for p=0.01:0.01:0.1
100*p 
end
```

The following was the output:

```
1
2
3
4 
5
6.000000000000001
6.999999999999999
8
9
10
```

I'd like to know why there is a slight error? Does this mean that, the accuracy in the general case is also as poor as it is in this case?

EDIT:

We compared the numbers -- `7==6.999999999999999` and the output was `0`. So, Matlab contradicts itself!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that 0.01 cannot be exactly represented in binary floating-point.  Neither can 0.07.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like a floating point precision "issue": http://www.lahey.com/float.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
x = ((0.07+1)*100) - 100
```

;-)

Comment: got excited 7% (value is 0.07) maps back to correct UI presentation, that is 7.


But then I tried this:

`[0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 0.10].map(n => ((n + 1) * 100) - 100)`

Output:
`(10) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9.000000000000014, 10.000000000000014]`

It's not working for other numbers, e.g., 9 and 10

Comment: That's true :/ and that's sad :'(
We could try `Math.round((n + 1) * 100)`, but it will only work with 2 decimals precision.