# Why does 55.0 / 1.1 equal 49.99999999999999?

Tags: ruby, floating-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why 6.84 - 3.6 == 3.2399999999999998](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721739/why-6-84-3-6-3-2399999999999998)

And by extension, why does 49.99999999999999 * 1.1 equal 55.0?

I assume this is do to with floating point arithmetic, but am somewhat perplexed as to why this occurs with such a simple sum, and why it is also true for the multiplication case.

Comment: Thanks, I did a search but couldn't find any resources on it.

Comment: Yeah, everybody has the same question but uses different numbers. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct, it is entirely to do with floating point arithmetic. Many decimal numbers are only representable to a certain accuracy in binary, which is why you see the  behaviour here. This isn't restricted to ruby - I'd suggest reading [What every computer scientist should know about floating point arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: Been a while since I've had to look at anything like this so thanks for the link!

Answer (score 3):

Your computer works in binary, not in decimal. The number 1.1 cannot be *exactly* represented in a finite binary representation, so it is necessarily an approximation.