# How do I round to two decimal places?

Tags: ruby, rounding

I want any items that are rounded such as this:

```
(5.101 * 100).round / 100.0
```

To be output like this:

```
5.10
```

Instead of this:

```
5.1
```

How do I do this in Ruby?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are a couple ways, but I favor using [String's `%`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-25) (format) operator:

```
'%.2f' % [(5.101 * 100).round / 100.0] # => "5.10"
```

Kernel's [`sprintf`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) method has the documentation for the various flags and modifiers. There's also Kernel's `printf` but, like I said, I'd go with `%`.

Comment: And? You're concerned because floating point isn't accurate? http://stackoverflow.com/q/10721739/128421

Comment: That's good, but your comments are not applicable to this question.

Comment: I see, it is about rounded numbers. Removing ... Thank you

Answer (score 8):

I hope it will help you.

```
2.0.0p195 :002 > (52.452158744).round(2)
=> 52.45 
2.0.0p195 :003 > (20.452158744).round(2)
=> 20.45 
2.0.0p195 :004 > (20.002555).round(2)
=> 20.0 
2.0.0p195 :005 > (20.012555).round(2)
=> 20.01
```

Comment: `(5.0).round(2)` returns `5.0` instead of `5.00`

Comment: `(5.0).round(2)` does rounding. It doesn't do formatting. They're different.